Low video quality of remote participant In react native Video SDK
I am using Zoom Video SDK in React Native.
https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/react-native/
The device where I am testing has:
Screen width: 1232
Screen height: 800
(by using Dimensions.get('window'))
I am testing in Landscape mode.
The local participant is fine.But remote participant’s video quality is very low and blurry.
My SDK version is 1.10, and the Android version is 9.
The code for displaying the full-screen remote participant is as follows:
<ZoomView
style={{
width: ‘100%’,
height: ‘100%’,
}}
userId={user.userId}
sharing={sharing}
preview={false}
isPiPView={false}
hasMultiCamera={false}
multiCameraIndex={false}
fullScreen={true}
videoAspect={VideoAspect.PanAndScan}
/>

The same configuration is used on both the caller and receiver apps.
The other device is mobile moto e13 and Android 13
I have tried VideoAspect.FullFilled But I makes it too much stretched.
I need full screen view of remote participant. How can make video quality better on my large device?.
Screen width: 1232
Screen height: 800
I have attached a screenshot for reference.


Is it still blurry if you setup as... style={{ width: ‘1232px’, height: ‘800px’ }}? Also try connecting to another device, your code might be fine and just in case this problem is specific only to Moto E13.
